# Remote debugging of my android device using google chrome is not showing browser inspect

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, remote-debugging

I am using an android device to debug my app through the google chrome browser.

It shows as my device is detected, but shows a message as **'No browser detected'**.

I used ADB devices command as well. But still cannot see browser inspect option.

[image: Here I have attached sample screenshot]

Comment: follow this page for step by step explanation https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: Have you enabled debugging?

Comment: No I couldn't. Still same issue.

Answer (score 1):

To debug the webview you need to enable debugging as below

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
}
```

More information is available at https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews

Comment: This is only true if you're debugging webView in an android app (APK), If you have a mobile browser specific bug showing up in  a normal website, that doesn't show up in emulators, you don't need this at all. It's misleading because the question does not mention webViews.

Answer (score 0):

At first make sure that

> Discover USB devices checkbox is enabled in the Settings right below the listed devices option.

Try changing the connected mode from Charging/ Transfer Files/ MIDI etc. Because it varies on different manufacturers.

Then only it might show the prompt(**RSA key fingerprint**) to allow connection with the connected computer.

If that also didn't work,
instead of opening the tab with `chrome://inspect` or `chrome://devices`

Follow these steps

- Right click on any tab and click inspect
- Go to sources tab
- On the extreme right click the three dots menu
- Click More Tools
- Select Remote Devices

Check that page, it may help you.